# Can anyone recommend an Android kiosk app that uses the Chrome browser?

Tags: android, chrome, kiosk

For instance, we've tried Fully Kiosk Browser and Kiosk Browser Lockdown, but they render our web pages too slowly. Chrome renders the same web pages on the same hardware in an acceptably timely fashion.

We can't change our web pages because they are part of a 3rd party web interface and work fine everywhere else.

Know of a kiosk with blacklist/whitelist ability that uses Chrome underneath?